# How to rewrite to from new URL to existing URL in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have same category name created into another subcategory.Newly created category URL is
New URL:http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/category/medicine-2 and existing category URL is
Existing URL:http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/category/medicine
I want to rewrite new URL(http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/category/medicine-2) to existing URL(http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/category/medicine).Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management
2. Click on Add URL Rewrite
3. For Create URL Rewrite, choose "Custom"
4. Give a random number or text for ID Path
5. Give the relative URL for old link as Request Path (category/medicine)
6. Relative URL for new link as Target path (category/medicine-2)
7. You may choose redirect as Permanent

and Save.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you don't have the same category **URL** under a subcategory.

Magento will automatically add a number at the end if that will be the case.

After you made sure you have unique URLs under the same category you can go to:

> Catalog > URL Rewrite Management

And search for your path to map it accordingly:

[image]

In target path you'll find the category ID to where is pointing you're URL.

Comment: Hi, This is not working.Please check my screenshot .what I am missing? https://prnt.sc/hgam1f .Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi, you're already having a path. Need first to delete the old one. Fix your category to have unique id and the reindex from: System > Index Manager.